# Copy Data Sink Validation

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to Use Copy data activity to check against sink values

My Data Sources:
SourceDataset : Source_SQL_DB
DestinationDataset : Destination_SQL_DB
SourceTable : SourceTableName
Column : Name,Age,Gender,Location
DestinationTable : DestinationTableName
Column : Name,Age,Gender,Location

Below is my scenario :
I have to validate Source before moving to sinkTable by checking Destination should not have the values
On Copy data, i can directly load data,

1. How to pass the Location in Source Query since my source will be connecting to source dataset only

   `select * from SourceTableName where Location in (select distinct Location  from DestinationTableName)`
2. How to check is the name present in the destination dataset table, If name is present, i should not insert data.

   `select * from SourceTableName where name not in (select distinct name from  DestinationTableName )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming both your source and sink are sql, you can use a lookup activity to get the list of names and location as comma seperated and either save them in a variable or use it to directly in source query.

Another way would be to load the source dara as is in staging table and then leveraging a stored procedure activity.

The final way would be to use dataflows